# If there is a Unique topological ordering in a dag then there exists a hamiltonian path

Tags: algorithm, topological-sort

How do you prove this ?
If there is a Unique topological ordering in a dag then there exists a hamiltonian path
Or is there a counter-example?

I proved the other direction of iff which is easy.

Comment: Can you think of a simple algorithm that attempts to construct a Hamiltonian path in a DAG? Can you think of a way that it might fail? What does that imply about the uniqueness of the topological order?

Comment: I think I found a proof. Any permutation of the unique top ord is Not a top ord. So if we exchange neighbour nodes in the unique top ord we get Not a top ord which means we have a backwards edge from the one node to the other. That's the only way it can be. Now about your question I think first we topologicaly sort the dag then the only correct node to start the hamiltonian path are the ones with no incoming edges. Anyone we pick at some point we will skip a node if there are not edges from each to each and we cannot return back because of the dag-topological order form of the graph.

Comment: So we are obliged to have edges from each to each node always pointing to the right in order to have a hamiltonian path. That's the only way to have a hamiltonian path. But why uniqueness of the top ord implies we have this form of the graph edges from each to each nodes always pointing to the right? My first proof proves it I think.

Comment: If it helps, there's a topological sorting algorithm that repeatedly chooses an arbitrary node with no incoming arcs to be next and deletes it (Kahn's algorithm).

Comment: I will check it out, thanks for your answer. Did I miss something in my thinking? I think proved it...